# History of knot enumeration tables

Tags: ho.history-overview, knot-theory

There is much arbitraryness in the Rolfsen (and later) tables.
Of course anyone would name $7_1$ to be the first knot with
$n=7$ crossings, but already my own "natural" ordering attempt
(extending Stasiak's work - I don't know if that has been refined later)
suggest at least for rational knots that beginning with $n=8$ the naming is unfortunate. Similar problems may occur for defining "+"/"-" for chiral
knots with writhe 0.

Is there anything known about the criteria for ordering knots
in the early knot tables? (And do the criteria differ from later tables,
say Thistlethwaite, where knot theory was much more advanced?)

Comment: I had assumed the ordering was the order they were discovered / enumerated.  I did not think there was any attempt to find a preferred order inside a given crossing number.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve spent some time looking at the knot table in Tait’s 1883-4 paper *On knots II*.  It seems that he places knots with large “twist regions” (that is, strings of bigons) later.  In particular, he places the $(2, 2k + 1)$ torus knots last (instead of first, as Rolfsen does) their crossing number class.  We probably have to forgive Tait for this — I think that the torus knots were only recognised as a class around 1911 (by Dehn and Schreier?)?